# Conjecture similar to Dirichlet's approximation theorem but with prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, approximation, pigeonhole-principle, diophantine-approximation

[Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) states that for any real numbers $\alpha,N$ with $1\leq N,$ there exist integers $p$ and $q$ such that $1\leq q\leq N$ and $\lvert q\alpha-p \rvert \leq \frac{1}{\lfloor N \rfloor + 1} < \frac{1}{N}.$

I wonder if the following is true, or if not, something closely related:

> For any real numbers $\alpha,N$ with $N>0,$ there exist
> integers $p$ and $q$ such that $q\in \lbrace{ \text{ first } \lceil N
>  \rceil \text{ primes } \rbrace}$ and $\lvert q\alpha-p \rvert <
>  \frac{1}{N}.$

I have failed to find a counter-example, but I also don't have many great ideas to prove it true. In particular, I doubt we can use the pigeon-hole principle proof of Dirichlet's theorem here, but maybe I am wrong about this?

I also don't see how [Minkowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem#Proof_by_Minkowski%27s_theorem) or the [generalisations to Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem#See_also) can help here.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted two days ago, Adam?

Comment: Yeah, I don't comprehend it very well. Sorry

Comment: You want to know how small $|q\alpha-p|$ gets. Motomäki shows it gets as small as $q^{-1/3+\epsilon}$, and no one has been able to come up with a better result. Just saying you don't comprehend it very well, doesn't give me very much to go on. What exactly don't you comprehend? What do you need?

Comment: I can't help you, if you won't communicate.

Comment: @GerryMyerson somewhat fair enough, although I needed time for your answer and comment to marinate. What you say, though, is about "infinitely many solutions." I only require one. So isn't my question not answered by your answer then?

Comment: OK, but you want it to be true for all $N$. A value of $q$ that works for some $N$ will no longer work if you take a much larger $N$; you'll need a different $q$ then. So you also need infinitely many solutions, not just one.

Comment: I believe a duplicate question was asked on mathoverflow a few years ago, although I can't find it right now.

Comment: You might be thinking of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221566/dirichlets-approximation-only-using-prime-power-as-denominator – a link I gave in a comment attached to the answer I posted here, Adam. By the way, if you found my answer at all useful, you might give some consideration to upvoting it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Gerry Myerson. Our expectation is that $|q\alpha-p|<1/q$ for infinitely many prime numbers $q$. It follows from Linnik’s conjecture on the least prime in an arithmetic progression. However, according to a result by Harman, we don't yet know how to do better than $|q\alpha-p|<c(\log q)/(q \log \log q)$ (see https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-72.2.241). Matomäki (2009) establsihed $|q\alpha-p|<q^{-1/3+\epsilon}$ unconditionally without any assumptions like the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis (GRH).

Answer (score 0):

"In the thirties of the last century, I. M. Vinogradov proved that the inequality $\|p\alpha\|\le p^{-1/5+\epsilon}$ has infinitely prime solutions $p$, where $\|.\|$ denotes the distance to a nearest integer. This result has subsequently been improved by many authors. In particular, Vaughan (1978) replaced the exponent $1/5$ by $1/4$ using his celebrated identity for the von Mangoldt function and a refinement of Fourier analytic arguments. The current record is due to Matomäki (2009) who showed the infinitude of prime solutions of the inequality $\|p\alpha\|\le p^{-1/3+\epsilon}$. This exponent $1/3$ is considered the limit of the current technology."

This is taken from the abstract of Stephan Baier and Esrafil Ali Molla, Diophantine approximation with prime denominator in real quadratic function fields, https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.01717

Comment: The paper is also published in Finite Fields and Their Applications, Volume 91,
2023, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ffa.2023.102242. The question also came up at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221566/dirichlets-approximation-only-using-prime-power-as-denominator